# UIWindow subviews do not autorotate

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am switching away from a split view controller in order to get two vertical table views side by side, just like the settings app. In my iPad AppDelegate I write the following code :

```
rootViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 270, 1004);
[window addSubview:rootViewController.view];

detailViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(270,20, 498, 1004);
[window addSubview:detailViewController.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This works great to get everything to show up in portrait just as it should. However when I rotate the device my rootViewController rotates, and the detail view controller does not. In both of my controllers I am implementing

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Only the "first" view in the UIWindow will have its rotation managed by the window. See [Technical Q&A QA1688](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html) for details.

If you're not going to use UISplitViewController, the next best thing would be to eliminate your root and detail view controllers and manage the views from one parent UIViewController.

And if you don't want to do that, you could try adding `rootViewController.view` and `detailViewController.view` as subviews inside one top-level UIViewController, but keep in mind that you will have to manage all the will/did appear/disappear and rotation method calls for the sub-controllers yourself, and some things will break because the subcontrollers' `parentViewController` will be nil rather than your top-level controller.

Comment: I was able to create a top level view to contain both my detail and root controller's views. Most typically I'd do a rewrite pushing it all into one controller, but there has already been a lot of time sunk into this two controller set up. Not ideal, it but it's all working now.