# Multiple UIWindows and which one controls the status bar orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

If you have an app with one `UIWindow`, my understanding is that the `rootViewController` of that `UIWindow` will be the `UIViewController` that receives the rotation/orientation methods like `shouldAutoRotate`, `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, etc.

I'm writing an external library and there is an instance where I create another `UIWindow` object, set its `rootViewController`, and make it key and visible.  It seems like the `rootViewController` of the original window is the one that still gets sent the rotation methods and not the new one.

I want to be able to control whether the application can rotate or not while the new window is visible, but it seems like the original window's `rootViewController` still has control over that.  I've tried setting the original window's `rootViewController` to a `rootViewController` that prohibits rotation of the screen while my new window is visible and resetting the original window's `rootViewController` to its original `rootViewController` but that causes some problems of its own.

Does anyone know how to make a certain `UIViewController` the one in charge of app rotation?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929836/uiwindow-subviews-do-not-autorotate

Answer (score 0):

How are you presenting the new viewController?  According to the documentation,the only viewControllers that are asked about `supportedInterfaceOrientations` are the root view controller, or a view controller that fills the screen. So, on an iPhone, your new viewController should receive the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` call if it is filling the screen (e.g., presented modally).

`shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` was deprecated as of iOS 6, so you should override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**This has worked for me...**

In my Case, the destination view appears correct but the status bar and also the UIKeyboard keeps the landscape configuration, making a real mess.

Working around After thousands of recommendations about statusBarOrientation and references read... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

"The setStatusBarOrientation:animated: method is not deprecated outright. It now works only if the supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most full-screen view controller returns 0. This makes the caller responsible for ensuring that the status bar orientation is consistent."

statusBarOrientation only works if supportedInterfaceOrientations returns 0, so... that give us a guess.

**If statusBarOrientation is not as expected, one zero return will do it (if always return 0, the view wont rotate, so:**

```
// if deviceOrientation is A (so I expect statusbarOrientation A
// but statusbarOrientation is B
// return 0
// otherwise 
// return user interface orientation for A

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        if(statusBarOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||statusBarOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
             return 0;
        }
    }
    // otherwise
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**Now, in viewDidAppear (believe me, I use this call even when the keyboard notification is recived:**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```